# Putting the results of an intersection of elements of a sigma algebra into a set.

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose I have a sigma algebra $\mathcal{M}$ indexed by $A$. Take $\alpha \in A, \beta \in A, \alpha \neq \beta$ and intersect $D_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{M}, D_{\beta} \in \mathcal{M}$

$$D_{\alpha} \bigcap D_{\beta} = D_r$$

where $D_r$ is the result of this intersection. Therefore $D_r = \emptyset$ in the case that $D_{\alpha}$ and $D_{\beta}$ are disjoint or $D_r = H_{\alpha \beta}$, where $H_{\alpha \beta}$ contains the elements in both $D_{\alpha}$ and $D_{\beta}$.

Repeat this process and put the results into the set $R$ and say each $H_{\alpha \beta} = \{\dots\}$ (a set, we don't care about the indices). My question is this:

Should

$$R = \{\emptyset, \{\dots\}, \{\dots\}, ...\}$$

or

$$R = \{\{\emptyset\}, \{\dots\}, \{\dots\}, ...\}$$

I believe the first to be true because we are just sticking the empty set into $R$. If not why?

Comment: Let me ask something to clarify: Is $H_{\alpha \beta}$ equal to $D_\alpha\cap D_\beta$? Also, is $R$ supposed to be the set all possible intersections?

Comment: @Wore Yes and yes.

Comment: Made a small edit. I believe the "first" to be true.

Comment: In that case, if you have that $D_\alpha\cap D_\beta=\emptyset$ (they are disjoint), then you should denote $R$ as in the first case: $R=\{\emptyset, ...\}$. However, given $D_\alpha\neq X$ (where $\mathcal{M}$ is a sigma algebra of subsets of $X$), you will have $D_\alpha\cap X=D_\alpha$, for every $\alpha\in A$, so it seems that $R$ is simply equals to $\mathcal{M}=R\setminus \{X\}$. (Notice that $X$ is the only set that you cannot obtain as the intersection of two different sets in $\mathcal{M}$).

Comment: I am not sure I understand your construction completely, however I've got a feeling you mean that $R \subseteq 2^\Omega$ where $\Omega$ is a set on which $\mathcal M$ is based (that is, $\Omega = \bigcup_{M\in\mathcal M} M$). In that case, the former is the correct way to write down $R$, and the latter actually means that $\emptyset \in \Omega$ which can be true when $\Omega$ is a collection of subsets of some other set, but I think it's not what you mean here.